# make widget rotate 90 degree after clicking in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to make the image rotate 90 degree after clicking with flutter code.

Click 1st and 4th, it works well with animation effect BUT

Click 2nd and 3nd, it rotates without animation effect. **<<<-- this is problem. I expect that it rotates with animation effect.**

I tried some other ways to implement but it did not work.

Can anyone help me explain What wrong is ?

I used the code as below:

```
import 'dart:math';    
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    
void main() => runApp(MyApp());    
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}    
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController1;
  AnimationController animationController2;
  AnimationController animationController3;
  AnimationController animationController4;
  Animation<double> animation1;
  Animation<double> animation2;
  Animation<double> animation3;
  Animation<double> animation4;
  int rotateTime = 0;    
  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController1 =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    animationController2 =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    animationController3 =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    animationController4 =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    animation1 =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi / 2).animate(animationController1);
    animation2 =
        Tween<double>(begin: pi / 2, end: pi).animate(animationController2);
    animation3 =
        Tween<double>(begin: pi, end: -pi / 2).animate(animationController3);
    animation4 =
        Tween<double>(begin: -pi / 2, end: 0).animate(animationController4);    
    super.initState();
  }    
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    animationController1?.dispose();
  }    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: _rotateChildContinuously,
            child:
                RotateTrans(Image.asset('images/smile.png'), buildAnimation())),
      ),
    );
  }    
  _rotateChildContinuously() {
    print(rotateTime);
    setState(() {
    rotateTime++;
    if (rotateTime == 1) {
      animationController1.forward(from: 0);
    } else if (rotateTime == 2) {
      animationController2.forward(from: pi / 2);
    } else if (rotateTime == 3) {
      animationController3.forward(from: pi);
    } else if (rotateTime == 4) {
      animationController4.forward(from: -pi / 2);
    }

    });
  }    
  Animation buildAnimation() {
    if (rotateTime == 1 || rotateTime == 0) {
      return animation1;
    } else if (rotateTime == 2) {
      return animation2;
    } else if (rotateTime == 3) {
      return animation3;
    } else if (rotateTime == 4) {
      rotateTime = 0;
      return animation4;
    }
  }
}    
class RotateTrans extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Animation<double> animation;    
  RotateTrans(this.child, this.animation);    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animation,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Container(
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: animation.value,
            child: Container(
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. change forward(from:0) or just animationControllerX.forward() without from parameter

   ```
   if (rotateTime == 1) {
           animationController1.forward(from:0);
         } else if (rotateTime == 2) {
           animationController2.forward(from:0);
         } else if (rotateTime == 3) {
           animationController3.forward(from:0);
         } else if (rotateTime == 4) {
           animationController4.forward(from:0);
         }
   ```
2. change formula of animation

   ```
       animation1 =
           Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi / 2).animate(animationController1);
       animation2 =
           Tween<double>(begin: pi / 2, end: pi).animate(animationController2);
       animation3 =
           Tween<double>(begin: pi, end: pi + pi/2).animate(animationController3);
       animation4 =
           Tween<double>(begin: pi + pi/2, end: pi + pi).animate(animationController4);
   ```

full code

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController1;
  AnimationController animationController2;
  AnimationController animationController3;
  AnimationController animationController4;
  Animation<double> animation1;
  Animation<double> animation2;
  Animation<double> animation3;
  Animation<double> animation4;
  int rotateTime = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController1 =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    animationController2 =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    animationController3 =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    animationController4 =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    animation1 =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi / 2).animate(animationController1);
    animation2 =
        Tween<double>(begin: pi / 2, end: pi).animate(animationController2);
    animation3 =
        Tween<double>(begin: pi, end: pi + pi/2).animate(animationController3);
    animation4 =
        Tween<double>(begin: pi + pi/2, end: pi + pi).animate(animationController4);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    animationController1?.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: _rotateChildContinuously,
            child:
            RotateTrans(Image.asset('assets/images/smile.png'), buildAnimation())),
      ),
    );
  }
  _rotateChildContinuously() {
    print(rotateTime);
    setState(() {
      rotateTime++;
      if (rotateTime == 1) {
        animationController1.forward(from:0);
      } else if (rotateTime == 2) {
        animationController2.forward(from:0);
      } else if (rotateTime == 3) {
        animationController3.forward(from:0);
      } else if (rotateTime == 4) {
        animationController4.forward(from:0);
      }

    });
  }
  Animation buildAnimation() {
    if (rotateTime == 1 || rotateTime == 0) {
      return animation1;
    } else if (rotateTime == 2) {
      return animation2;
    } else if (rotateTime == 3) {
      return animation3;
    } else if (rotateTime == 4) {
      rotateTime = 0;
      return animation4;
    }
  }
}
class RotateTrans extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Animation<double> animation;
  RotateTrans(this.child, this.animation);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animation,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Container(
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: animation.value,
            child: Container(
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should dispose the animation before calling super.dispose() to avoid an exception